# Rundeck SchedulerException: The Scheduler has been shutdown

Tags: grails, rundeck

Centos 7 running rundeck 3.2.5-20200403

I restored my server backup (and db backup) for rundeck and rundeckdb respectively, booted the servers, and restarted the services.

But after that in the logs it is showing the following during startup:

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

[2020-04-16 13:11:17.229]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Starting Rundeck 3.2.5-20200403 (2020-04-03) ...
[2020-04-16 13:11:17.292]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] using rdeck.base config property: /var/lib/rundeck
[2020-04-16 13:11:17.330]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] loaded configuration: /etc/rundeck/framework.properties
[2020-04-16 13:11:17.509]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] RSS feeds disabled
[2020-04-16 13:11:17.510]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Using jaas authentication
[2020-04-16 13:11:17.538]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Preauthentication is disabled
[2020-04-16 13:11:20.671]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
[2020-04-16 13:11:22.714]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck startup finished in 6095ms
[2020-04-16 13:11:24.380]  WARN ScheduledExecutionService --- [pool-1-thread-2] Attempt to schedule job Scheduled/Monthly/Export Users [474b94bc-361a-4fb3-9550-855dbabcf24b] in project O365_Extended_Toolkit, but job execution is disabled.
[2020-04-16 13:11:25.710]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck Shutdown detected
[2020-04-16 13:11:25.730] ERROR SessionImpl --- [pool-1-thread-2] HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Session is closed!]
[2020-04-16 13:11:25.958] ERROR GrailsHibernateTransactionManager --- [pool-1-thread-2] Commit exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:296)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:590)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
        at rundeck.services.ScheduledExecutionService.rescheduleJobs(ScheduledExecutionService.groovy)
        at rundeck.services.ScheduledExecutionService.rescheduleJobs(ScheduledExecutionService.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at rundeck.services.ScheduledExecutionService$__tt__rescheduleJobsAsync_closure151.doCall(ScheduledExecutionService.groovy:697)
        at rundeck.services.ScheduledExecutionService$__tt__rescheduleJobsAsync_closure151.doCall(ScheduledExecutionService.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:499)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies I didn't look deeper but I realized that the port was in use by my sshd session.

So I killed my sshd session and used a native console to start the service, wait for it to start completely and then login via sshd.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:4443
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:143)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```